# setting rowspan in td table

Tags: html

i wanna create something like this in my table

[image]

i try with this code, but the result far from what i want

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td rowspan="3">No</td>
       <td rowspan="3">Item1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>SubItem1a</td>
       <td>Subitem1b</td>
       <td>Subitem1c</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>AnotherSub1a</td>
       <td>AnotherSub1b</td>
       <td>AnotherSub1c</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td rowspan="3">No</td>
       <td rowspan="3">Item1</td>
       <td>
          <tr>SubItem1a</tr>
          <tr>Subitem1b</tr>
          <tr>Subitem1c</tr>
       </td>
       <td>
          <tr>AnotherSub1a</tr>
          <tr>AnotherSub1b</tr>
          <tr>AnotherSub1c</tr>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

how to archive table like image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now used to this code **[rowspan Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp)**

```html
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" align="center">No</td>
      <td rowspan="3" align="center">Item1</td>
      <td>SubItem1a</td>
      <td>SubItem1a</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Subitem1b</td>
      <td>Subitem1c</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>AnotherSub1b</td>
      <td>AnotherSub1c</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: nice it's what i looking for..i will accept your answer..still 8 minutes more

Comment: hm...i wonder why in my table it's failt to make `No` & `Item1' to center vertical /horizontal

Answer (score 1):

This will help with your future reference.

I did some example hopefully you understand what is rowspan and colspan.

```
<h1> Without using Rowspan </h1>

<table border="1">

            <tr>
                <th>How</th>
                <th>it</th>
                <th>Work</th>
                <th>Rowspan</th>
                <th>First</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td >20</td>
                <td >30</td>
                <td  >40</td>
                <td >50</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>60</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>110</td>
            </tr>


        </table>

<hr>


<h1> using Rowspan </h1>

<table border="1">

            <tr>
                <th>How</th>
                <th>it</th>
                <th>Work</th>
                <th>Rowspan</th>
                <th>First</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">10</td>
                <td rowspan="2">20</td>
                <td rowspan="2">30</td>
                <td rowspan="2" >40</td>
                <td >50</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>60</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>110</td>
            </tr>


        </table>


    <hr>


<h1> using colspan </h1>

<table border="1">

     <tr>
                <th colspan="5">Hello World</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>How</th>
                <th>it</th>
                <th>Work</th>
                <th>Rowspan</th>
                <th>First</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">10</td>
                <td rowspan="2">20</td>
                <td rowspan="2">30</td>
                <td rowspan="2" >40</td>
                <td >50</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>60</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>110</td>
            </tr>


        </table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sgatLLpr/3/)